# Report unused imports as error in Android Studio or IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import, android-studio-import

Is there any way/setting in Android Studio to report the unused imports in java files as error?

In Eclipse, lint reported this as error pretty easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Applies to Android Studio and IntelliJ**

You could go to `File/Settings` then browse to Editor/Inspections/Import.

Change Severity of Unused Import to `Error`

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in Intellij.  Setting this and then rebuilding the project with unused imports doesn't report any errors or even warnings.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

---

its automatically remove unused imports

**yourProject --> Right Click --> Optimize Imports**

---

lint  : its also show unused imports in java files as error

**yourProject --> Right Click --> Analize --> Inspect Code**

Answer (score 1):

First remove references of these imports from the code. 
Then you can use this shortcut 
 `ALT + CTRL + O`

Answer (score 1):

For **Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4**, follow this **Android Studio** -> **Preferences** -> **Editor** -> **General** -> **Auto Import**

[image]