# How to prevent Intellij Scala compiler from marking unused imports as errors?

Tags: scala, gradle, intellij-idea

I am using the Scala Intellij plugin, and after a recent Intellij update I've found that when I attempt to build (using Gradle), I now get compilation errors for all unused imports in the project. I'm trying to figure out how to turns those down to warnings like they should be.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357679/report-unused-imports-as-error-in-android-studio-or-intellij) is related, but not the fix, as it discusses Intellij editor level errors (like the kind of thing you'd get a red squiggly line for in your editor). This does not manifest until I press the build button.

EDIT: build.gradle was requested, here's the relevant section:

```
compileScala {
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = [
        "-target:jvm-1.8",
        "-feature",
        "-Xno-patmat-analysis",
        "-Xfatal-warnings",
        "-Xlint:_",
        "-deprecation",
        "-unchecked",
        "-Xlint:-infer-any",
        "-Xlint:-unsound-match"
    ]
    scalaCompileOptions.forkOptions.with {
        jvmArgs = ["-Xms512M",
                   "-Xmx4096M",
                   "-Xss4M",
                   "-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024M"]
    }
}
```

It seems like the `-Xfatal-warnings` bit is the problem, but that's always been there, and never caught unused import errors before. Only when combined with an Intellij update did it cause a problem.

Comment: can you show us the build.gradle file to see if there's any config forcing that behaviour?

Comment: The [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help a lot.

Comment: Why do you have unused imports? They are useless.

Comment: Agree that unused imports are useless, working on an open source project and just didn't want to have to make a bunch of changes all at once. The build.gradle file hasn't changed at all, so I didn't think it would be that. All that changed was an intellij update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Xfatal-warnings` compiler option is the cause of your problem. Remove this option and it should build fine with warnings in the code.

Comment: Removing this did fix it, so I'm going to accept this answer. I definitely had this argument in the past though so I suspect something in IntelliJ changed for it to start picking up on it.